# How does this loop work

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:
1.

```
var count = 0;

while(count < 3){
    //Your code goes here!
    console.log("I'm looping!")
    count++;
}
```

The output:
I'm looping!
I'm looping!
I'm looping!
2

Question: Why the output contain a '2'?

2.

```
count=1;
do {
    console.log("start");
}

while(count < 3){

    console.log("I'm looping!")
    count++;
}
```

Question: This loop is going infinite loop, what's wrong with it?

Comment: can you show the problem in a fiddle, seems strange to me.

Comment: how could go infinite?

Comment: @Girish the browser is stoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop does not really output `2`. You see it in the console, because the console also outputs the result of the last expression of your code, which would be `count` before it is incremented one final time.

In your second loop, only the first code-block belongs to the loop (`do .... while`). In it, the count variable never gets incremented, so you've got an infinite loop.

**EDIT:**

To get your second loop working the way you would expect, you need to be aware of how the `do...while` loop works. Contrary to normal `while` loops, they are at least executed once. The part that will be looped over is the code between `do` and `while`.

So I guess, the code you want would look something like this:

```
count=1;
console.log("start");

do {
    console.log("I'm looping!")
    count++;
}
while(count < 3)
```

Comment: so how can I change the code to solve question two??

Comment: and question one is showing 2 after three "I'm looping", is it because I am doing a tutorial or?

Comment: It is, because you are putting the code into the browser's console (I guess? It is the console that pops up by pressing `F12` in your browser.) This console always, automatically, outputs the last evaluated expression in the code you gave it. So after running the first example code, it outputs `2`, because that is the result of the last `count++`.